# Get a GuildMember's nickname and status type in Discord.js v12

Tags: discord.js

The title's pretty much everything. I have tried `` .addField(`**Nickname (If Applicable):**`, `${usr.nickname}`) `` but it says `undefined` in the embed... For the presence though, I've tried `` .addField(`**Status:**`, `${usr.presence}`) ``. That gives me `[object Object]` in the embed. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you're not able to get a GuildMember object's status but would have to first turn it into a user object.
This can be easily done as follows:

```
const memberObject = <guild>.members.cache.get('place id here') // Gives you the member object
// or alternatively you could search for him using his name using the .find() function
const userObject = memberObject.user // Gives you the user object of the member
```

From there on, we could simply check the user's nickname and status using:

```
console.log(userObject.presence.status)
console.log(memberObject.nickname)
```

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: You can't imagine how much this helped. Thanks so much bro! <3

Comment: I have a question though.. For the nickname, could I have done `usr.id.nickname` or would that not have worked?

Comment: It wouldn't work, since 'id' and 'nickname' are both 'user' extensions.

Comment: Also for anyone wondering. If you want to get the status as `online`, `dnd` etc. You have to do ```presence.status```